# How can I use resize property on images?

Tags: html, css, image, frontend

One way I found to use resize on an image, is to put some element like div or something, and through CSS put the image as a background image.
I couldn't make the image appear at 100% all of the time.
What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `resize`-property. Note that it not works on inline elements or elements with `overflow="visisble"`

```css
div {
  display: block;
  resize: horizontal;;
  overflow: hidden;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  max-width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x90.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: ok but how do I present the all image in any scale? because when I resize, the image is cut and only the div is resized..

Comment: Then you need to know the aspect ratio of the image and use it on the div itself. then only allow horizontal or vertical resize as then the div will maintain the same aspect ratio as the image.